# Why I obtain this "Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric" into this simple insert query on Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, rdbms

I am pretty new to database and I have some problem with this insert query that insert a record on a **Microsoft SQL Server**.

So I have this **QS_TirPolizza** table having the following fields:

```
ID  bigint
Polizzaid   bigint
BankerID    varchar
ReteVendita varchar
PercentualeRendimentoDaInizioGestione   decimal
PercentualeRendimentoDaInizioAnno   decimal
PercentualeRendimentoDaInizioTrimestre  decimal
DataCalcoloBF   datetime
AnnoRiferimento int
PremioInizialeVersato   money
PremiVersatiInAnnoRiferimento   money
ImportiRiscattatiInAnnoRiferimento  money
CedoleErogateInAnnoRiferimento  money
ControvaloreTotale  money
DataRiferimentoNav  datetime
RisultatoAnnuoInAnnoRiferimento money
PremioInizialeVersatoDaInizioGestione   money
PremiVersatiDaInizioGestione    money
ImportiRiscattatiDaInizioGestione   money
CedoleErogateDaInizioGestione   money
RisultatoAnnuoDaInizioGestione  money
CapitaleCasoMorte   money
Timestamp   datetime
QuoteTotale decimal
PercentualeRendimentoDaInizioMese   decimal
PercentualeRendimentoDaInizioSemestre   decimal
ControvaloreTotaleAnnoPrecedente    money
DataControvaloreTotaleAnnoPrecedente    datetime
MsgPercentualeRendimentoDaInizioAnno    varchar
MsgPercentualeRendimentoDaInizioGestione    varchar
MsgPercentualeRendimentoDaInizioMese    varchar
MsgPercentualeRendimentoDaInizioSemestre    varchar
MsgPercentualeRendimentoDaInizioTrimestre   varchar
isTirAnomalo    bit
```

And this is my insert query:

```
insert into QS_TirPolizza(
    annoRiferimento, 
    bankerID, 
    controvaloreTotale, 
    dataCalcoloBF, 
    dataRiferimentoNav, 
    percentualeRendimentoDaInizioAnno, 
    percentualeRendimentoDaInizioGestione, 
    percentualeRendimentoDaInizioMese, 
    percentualeRendimentoDaInizioSemestre, 
    percentualeRendimentoDaInizioTrimestre, 
    polizzaId, 
    premioInizialeVersato, 
    premioInizialeVersatoDaInizioGestione, 
    quoteTotale, 
    reteVendita, 
    timestamp, 
    isTirAnomalo 
) values  ( 
    2015, 
    'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 
    2993197.200971, 
    '2015-05-30 14:22:54', 
    '2015-05-30 14:22:56', 
    -139852.94674, 
    -0.22452, 
    null, 
    null, 
    -115890.54469,
     123456789, 
    2999932.770000, 
    2999932.770000, 
    255388.71925, 
    'TEST', 
    '2015-05-30 14:23:25', 
    0 
)
```

Where the fields **percentualeRendimentoDaInizioAnno**, **percentualeRendimentoDaInizioGestione**, **percentualeRendimentoDaInizioMese**, **percentualeRendimentoDaInizioSemestre**, **percentualeRendimentoDaInizioTrimestre** have **decimal** as type on the table definition.

The problem is that performing the previous query I obtain the following error message and the record is not inserted:

> 15:00:14  [INSERT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 8115, SQL
>   State: S0008]  Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data
>   type numeric.

I think that the problem is that these values have to much digits because reducing the digits related to the entire and to the decimal sections of these number it works fine. Infact this second version of the query (that have number with less digits for the previous fields) works fine:

```
insert into QS_TirPolizza(
    annoRiferimento, 
    bankerID, 
    controvaloreTotale, 
    dataCalcoloBF, 
    dataRiferimentoNav, 
    percentualeRendimentoDaInizioAnno, 
    percentualeRendimentoDaInizioGestione, 
    percentualeRendimentoDaInizioMese, 
    percentualeRendimentoDaInizioSemestre, 
    percentualeRendimentoDaInizioTrimestre, 
    polizzaId, 
    premioInizialeVersato, 
    premioInizialeVersatoDaInizioGestione, 
    quoteTotale, 
    reteVendita, 
    timestamp, 
    isTirAnomalo 
) values  ( 
    2015, 
    'XXX123YYY', 
    2993197.200971, 
    '2015-05-30 14:22:54', 
    '2015-05-30 14:22:56', 
    -139.9, 
    -0.22, 
    null, 
    null, 
    -110.54469,
     1234567890, 
    2999932.770000, 
        2999932.770000, 
        255388.71925,
    'ISPB', 
    '2015-05-30 14:23:25', 
    0 
)
```

These value are generated by a Java application and I can't truncate it so what can I do? Exist some better data type that can correctly contain these data on SQL server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mention the size of the Datatype while creating tables in SQL Server. In your case you should mention precision and scale. Please alter your table datatype like the below.

```
Decimal to Decimal(18,6)
Varchar to Varchar(500)
```

Once you made the appropriate changes then run your insert script

Answer (score 1):

You have some columns which needs decimal point, but in the table definition you used `Decimal` as data type. You should pay attention that `Decimal` data type has not any decimal point and if you need any decimal point you need to define it as `Decimal(X,X)`.

So columns such as `controvaloreTotale` which has decimal point should be get `Decimal(X,X)` data type.

[Decimal Data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)